# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and GraphQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Does anyone have support information for GRAPHQL by WSO2 EI?

I need to consume API that is using this technology and I found nothing for EI only for APIM

Best Regards,

Alberto B. Paulino
São Paulo Capital: +55 (11) 4780-4940 
alberto.paulino@ciatecnica.com.br | www.ciatecnica.com.br

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EI does not have GraphQL support at the moment. (Latest version at the moment EI 6.6, Micro Integrator 1.1)